# Drupal 7 form alter required field is not working when i used field from "Add existing field"

Tags: forms

I have added two fields in to my custom content type using "Add existing field".

For specific URL, I need to set these two fields as Required.

So I have altered my form and set required condition. After setting it, I have printed the form using devel, these fields are having required settings.

```
$form['field_name']['und']['#required'] = TRUE;
$form['field_email']['und']['#required'] = 1;
dsm($form);
```

But required condition is not applied.

[image]
[image]

That is, I could not see red color required indication as well as its not working in the form submit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
$form['field_email']['und']['0']['value']['#required'] = TRUE;
```

and if not work then try

```
$form['field_email']['und']['0']['#required'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: @kalidasan your welcome :).

Comment: @kalidasan please if you get your answer mark the answer as correct

Comment: Thanks for the ['value'] tip. That's what was missing for me.

Comment: @mcaleaa your welcome, it get me  good sense  that my answers help others in future :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up needing an additional value set to make this work and thoguht others might benefit from knowing so:

```
$form['profile_personal_information']['field_company'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#required'] = 1;
$form['profile_personal_information']['field_company'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#required'] = TRUE;
$form['profile_personal_information']['field_company'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#required'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Field Validation module](https://drupal.org/project/field_validation):

> This module adds an extra tab to each field instance, allowing you to specify validation rules for your field instances.

Or use [hook_field_validate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_validate/7) in you custom module.

Comment: Is this module need for this small fix?